# Input Caret displaying behind Absolute Positioned Div in IE

Tags: html, forms, input

I have the following issue that can be seen here http://fiddle.jshell.net/vy4QG/2/ and only in IE.

This is just a small example. My site has a long form and static footer navigation.

When you tab through the inputs you will notice that the caret still blinks even though it is behind another div.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Again...Only happens in IE.

Comment: I don't know of a way without some polyfill.  You can have the inputs positioned off the page, and have a div put in their place.  On every change of the input, update the div.  Seems like a pain.

Comment: I've edited the code a bit to show what it would look like on my site. http://fiddle.jshell.net/vy4QG/2/
grey div at the bottom would be the fixed navigation.

Comment: Can't really understand what you want to happen (or not happen). Do you want the caret to **not** blink whenever it's under the fixed nav?

This might help you; http://stackoverflow.com/a/3807022/2365602

Comment: I want the caret to NOT blink when behind something else. In my case I do not think that would work as great. The forms are quite long and the page is scroll able obviously. I want the behavior of other browsers. When tabbing through the inputs and it gets to the lower ones behind the nav the blinking should stop, but when scrolling down it should show again. I hope that makes sense. Load the link I provided in IE and you will see the issue.